# Store, display and update new data in android firebase

Tags: android, android-layout, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm pretty new to coding native. I've been following a tutorial and adapting it to my own app.

My issue comes in with the user profile, in the tutorial the profile is limited to uploading and updating the user profile picture and updating the username.

For my profile page, I would like to introduce new data. Personal 'employee' data that I would like to store in the Firebase database.

I would like this data to be stored first when entered. I would then like it to be displayed in the fields on the profile page and for them to be updated, if the values are changed and the update button is clicked.

[The tutorial](https://www.udemy.com/android-and-firebase-create-a-live-status-update-app/) I've been following is a course offered by udemy

I've also tried adapting some other code, with no luck. (I, unfortunately, cannot post more than two links. Apologies for the screenshot.)

[These are the links to code I've tried adapting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yalli.png)

Listed below are snippets of the profile layouts. The tutorials xml is first, followed by my desired layout.

Tutorial:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/userImageViewProfile"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/userNameEditTextProfile"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/updateProfileButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Update"
    />
```

Mine:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/userImageViewProfile"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/userNameProfile"
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/profTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_fields"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Profession"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/profReg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_fields"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Registration Number"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/profCall"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_fields"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Contact Number"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/profEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_fields"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Email Address"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/profID"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_fields"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="South African ID Number"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/profBank"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_fields"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Bank Account Number"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/updateProfileButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
            android:text="Update"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Title/Profession, registration, contact number, ID number and bank account are all new fields.

Any and all help is appreciated.

**NOTE UPDATE**

I have tried creating a class and working from there.

Class:

```
public class UserInfo {

public String name;
public String title;
public String reg;
public String phone;
public String email;
public String id;
public String bank;

public UserInfo () {

}

public UserInfo(String name, String title, String reg, String phone, String email,String id,String bank) {
    this.name = name;
    this.title = title;
    this.reg = reg;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.email = email;
    this.id = id;
    this.bank = bank;
}
```

}

Activity:

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

//firebase auth object
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

//view objects
private EditText userNameProfile;
private EditText profEmail;

//defining a database reference
private DatabaseReference mUsersDB;

//our new views
private EditText profTitle, profReg, profCall, profID, profBank;
private Button updateProfileButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    if(mAuth.getCurrentUser() == null){
        goToLogin();
    }

    //getting the database reference
    mUsersDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    //getting the views from xml resource
    profTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.profTitle);
    profReg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.profReg);
    profCall = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.profCall);
    profID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.profID);
    profBank = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.profBank);
    updateProfileButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.updateProfileButton);

    updateProfileButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    //initializing views
    userNameProfile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userNameProfile);
    profEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.profEmail);

    updateProfileButton.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(mAuth.getCurrentUser() == null){
        goToLogin();
    }
}

private void goToLogin(){
    startActivity(new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));

}

private void saveUserInformation() {
    //Getting values from database
    String title = profTitle.getText().toString().trim();
    String reg = profReg.getText().toString().trim();
    String phone = profCall.getText().toString().trim();
    String id = profID.getText().toString().trim();
    String bank = profBank.getText().toString().trim();


    //creating a userinformation object
    UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo(title, reg, phone, id, bank);

    //getting the current logged in user
    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    //saving data to firebase database
    mUsersDB.child(user.getUid()).setValue(userInfo);

    //displaying a success toast
    Toast.makeText(this, "Information Saved...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    if(view == updateProfileButton){
        saveUserInformation();
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you can give these fields blank value at the time of user signed in.
like

```
   DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

                                HashMap<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                userMap.put("name", "");
                                userMap.put("contact","");
                                userMap.put("ID Number","");
                                userMap.put("Profile Title","");

                                mDatabase.setValue(userMap);
```

and when the user update these values, it will update specific value in firebase database using

`Map updateMap = new HashMap();` instead of ***HashMap***

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can create a UserInfo class where you can store fileds you need.

```
    public class UserInfo { 

public String name;
public String title;
public String reg;
public String phone;
public String email;
public String id;
public String bank;

public UserInfo () { 

} 

public UserInfo(String name, String title,String reg, String email,String id,String bank) {
    this.name = name;
    this.title = title;
    this.reg = reg;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.email = email;
    this.id = id;
    this.bank = bank;
} 
}
```

and when you want to save the data, just create the object of this UserInfo class and assign values accordingly.

```
  UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo(title, reg, phone, id, bank);
...
```

Handle error scenarios as well.

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
String key =user.getUid();
mDatabase = mDatabase.child(key);
mDatabase.setValue(userInfo );
```

It will save directly data into the `Users` child with unique key

I Hope it will help

Comment: Hi, I have tried something similar about 10 minutes ago. I run into an error when creating a user information object. "UserInfo is abstract; cannot be instantiated." I'm not sure if I am doing it correctly 

Comment: Create your own class named Employee  as I have created in answer

Comment: I have. My class is just called "UserInfo" instead of "Employee"

Comment: Then you need to extend UserInfo and create a new class where you will add the fields.

Comment: I updated my post if it makes it easier to understand what I did.

Comment: please check updated answer, your UserInfo class should contain contructor matching the parameters.

Comment: then create a new class by extending UserInfo